# How do I indent a table within the itemize environment?

Tags: tables, lists, indentation, itemize

I'd like to know how to indent a table within the `itemize` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello. I love \LaTeX! I have a question:
\begin{itemize}
    \item
        How can I indent the table below?

        \begin{tabular}{|rcccl|}
            \hline\\[-10pt]
            this & table & should & be & indented \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could prepend the `tabular` with an `\hspace*{<len>}` where `<len>` is any known (La)TeX length unit. For example, below I've spaced the `tabular` by `2em`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello. I love \LaTeX! I have a question:
\begin{itemize}
    \item
        How can I indent the table below?

        \hspace*{2em}\begin{tabular}{|rcccl|}
            \hline
            this & table & should & be & indented \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}​
```

Using the starred version of `\hspace*{<len>}` here is not compulsory - `\hspace{<len>}` would also work.

Note how it is necessary to "unskip" the distance inserted after `\hline` via `\\`. I've just removed it from my MWE. Of course, other lengths also exist that you could use (`\labelsep` comes to mind, which is the length between the bullet and the start of the item text).

Comment: Great answer, thank you! May I ask what the function of the * is in general?

Comment: See [Help with `\hspace`](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-241.html) for some detail on the use of `*` or not.